# Python 2.7 + SQL Alchemy 1115, "Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'"

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I have a Python 2.7 automation script that collects data from multiple sources and generates a report. It uses sqlalchemy to get some data from MySQL DB. The script works well with the venv created couple of months ago. But if try to recreate the venv using the same requirement.txt file and run the script it fails on getting the data from DB with the error message:

sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1115, u"Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'")

The specific package versions are not specified in the requirements.txt file, however the environments look very similar, at least the sqlalchemy version is the same in both.

Any ideas why one of the environments work while the second doesn't and how could it be fixed?
This is the way how I work with the DB.

```
        engine = create_engine(
           'mysql+pymysql://{user}:{pwd}@{host}/{db_name}'.format(
                user=self.user,
                pwd=self.pwd,
                host=self.server,
                db_name=self.db_name
            ),
            echo=False,
            pool_pre_ping=True,
            pool_size=100,
            pool_recycle=7200,
        )
        LOGGER.info('Created: %s', engine)
        self.session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine, autoflush=False, autocommit=False))
    ....

    def execute_sql(self, sql_request):
        """Execute SQL query

        :param (str) sql_request: SQL query
        :return: (obj) query execution result
        """
        result = self.session.execute(sql_request)
        return result
```

The error I mentioned occurs on self.session.execute(sql_request)

Comment: What happens if you set up the new environment using an "old_requirements.txt" file generated by `pip freeze > old_requirements.txt` in the old environment?

Comment: Good question, let me try and see. However I recolved this by addinf an explicit charset into create_engine: mysql+pymysql://{user}:{pwd}@{host}/{db_name}?charset=utf8'